# SwiftUI TabView and NavigationView Mixed - Pop To Root doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, combine

Seems obvious that when I use both TabView and NavigationView - Pop To Root doesn't work.
This is two test codes I've implemented. One with both tabView and NavigationView, one with only Navigation View.

1. Code with both TabView and NavigationView

```
import SwiftUI

class Views: ObservableObject {
  @Published var stacked = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var views = Views()
  @State var selection: Int = 0

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      TabView(selection: $selection) {
        ContentView2()
      }
    }
    .environmentObject(views)
  }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var views: Views
  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView3(), isActive: $views.stacked) {
      Text("Go to View 2")
    }
    .isDetailLink(false)
  }
}

struct ContentView3: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var views: Views

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button("Pop to root") {
        self.views.stacked = false
      }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("View 3")
  }
}
```

2. Code only NavigationView

- Just remove `TabView` bracket from Code and it works like charm...

When I try to pop to root in tabview, there shows a log
`Trying to pop to a missing destination at /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros/Monoceros-120/Shared/NavigationBridge_PhoneTV.swift:341`

Has anybody found a way top TabView and NavigationView, and implement pop To Root?

Answer (score 0):

give a try to this:

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isActive : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ContentView2(rootIsActive: self.$isActive),
                isActive: self.$isActive
            ) {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
            .isDetailLink(false)
            .navigationBarTitle("Root")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @Binding var rootIsActive : Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ContentView3(rootIsActive: self.$rootIsActive)) {
            Text("Hello, World #2!")
        }
        .isDetailLink(false)
        .navigationBarTitle("Two")
    }
}

struct ContentView3: View {
    @Binding var rootIsActive : Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ContentView4(shouldPopToRootView: self.$rootIsActive)) {
            Text("Hello, World #3!")
        }
        .isDetailLink(false)
        .navigationBarTitle("Three")
    }
}

struct ContentView4: View {
    @Binding var shouldPopToRootView : Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World #4!")
            Button (action: { self.shouldPopToRootView = false } ){
                Text("Pop to root")
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Four")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```